# How do I apt-get source squid on Xenial and rebuild the package

Tags: apt, squid, source

I've installed squid using `apt-get install squid`, and it's installed squid 3.x.  However I need to compile `--with-openssl` however when I attempt `apt-get source squid` it redirects to the `squid3` (dummy) package and complains that there is no source.

An answer elsewhere suggested getting debian source, but the suggested instruction doesn't work and I suspect the question predates xenial, so how do I go about installing (and rebuilding) the source package for squid?

Best I've found so far, is an answer from 2007 on https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=68246 which stumbles at the above hurdle.

Comment: Do you have the `deb-src` lines in `/etc/apt/sources.list` uncommented (to match the equivalent `deb` lines that're uncommented)?

Comment: great minds.  I just checked that myself, and no, I'm an idiot

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I'm stupid.  `apt-cache search squid` showed that squid came from the `main` ubuntu repository and `/etc/apt/sources.list` showed all `deb-src` entries were commented out.

Un-commenting the `security.ubuntu.com`...`main` entry, followed by `sudo apt-get update` and now `apt-get source squid` works fine